# How to configure Skype on MacOS to mute other programs (i.e., Pandora) when in a call?

Tags: macos, mac, skype

I have heard that Skype can mute other programs during calls.
I'm on MacOS. 
It does mute iTunes but it does not mute Pandora or other programs.

Is there a way to fix this?